# Modifying the length of a dictionary to a determined value and leave the keys with the highest values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys so I'm working on this script where I need to update a dictionary `words` with the most frequent words limited to the value of `limit`.

```
from typing import List, Dict, TextIO, Tuple
def most_frequent(words: Dict[str, int], limit: int) -> None:

new_dict = {}
new_list = []
#I decided to create a list for easier sort

for w in words:
    new_list.append((keys, words.get(w)))
    new_list.sort(key=sorting, reverse=True)
    #key=sorting: used to sort by the value of the key from big to small 

for n_w in new_list:
    if len(new_dict) < limit:
        new_dict[n_w[0]] = n_w[1]
#this part add the words to a new dictionary up to the value of limit

words = new_dict
print(words)
#print just to check my result, I know it's supposed to return None
```

Here is the problem, I need to achieve the below test cases where: `len(words) <= limit`, if the most frequent words are added and results in `len(words) > limit` then none of those are added; and if the last word is not unique and has the same value as the next one, none of those get added either.

```
>>> most_frequent({'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 3, 'rat': 1}, 4)
{'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 3}
#This one passes

>>> most_frequent({'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 2, 'rat': 2}, 4)
{'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3}
#what I get {'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 2},  'bee' doesn't get added because is tied with 'rat'

>>> most_frequent({'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 3, 'rat': 1}, 3)  
{}
#what I get {'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3}, none of them are added because there are 4 with high frequency but if they get added words > limit and it can't be
```

I feel that the approach that I'm using right now is not efficient for what I need and I'm stuck in the last two cases. I'm not allowed to use modules, what approach should I use? or at least what can I improve here to get what I need?

Comment: Why `most_frequent({'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 3, 'rat': 1}, 3)` should be empty? I think it will be best if you explain the reason behind each output.

Comment: @DanielMesejo I just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def most_frequent(words, limit):
    frequencies = words.items()
    inverse = {}
    for word, frequency in frequencies:
        inverse.setdefault(frequency, []).append(word)

    result = {}
    remaining = limit
    for frequency in sorted(inverse.keys(), reverse=True):
        if len(inverse[frequency]) <= remaining:
            result.update({word: frequency for word in inverse[frequency]})
            remaining -= len(inverse[frequency])
        else:
            break

    return result


print(most_frequent({'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 3, 'rat': 1}, 4))
print(most_frequent({'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 2, 'rat': 2}, 4))
print(most_frequent({'cat': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'bee': 3, 'rat': 1}, 3))
```

**Output**

```
{'bee': 3, 'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'cat': 3}
{'dog': 3, 'pig': 3, 'cat': 3}
{}
```

The idea is to create an inverted dictionary (`inverse`) where the keys are the frequencies and the values are list of words with that frequency, then you could iterate over the frequencies in non ascending order, and add a list of words to the final result only if the remaining budget allows it.

Comment: I see what you did! is better to have the key values as keys, okay hold on let me assimilate this